# How to transfer or upload ALL my Gmail photos for years to Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I want to find a program or somehow a way to have Google Photos scan my entire emails (Gmail) to find my attached pictures.  I do not want to look at each pic and upload it.  I have thousands and I am someone who never deletes emails in Google.  Any ideas would be great.  I can pay for storage as well.  I just want every single photo I have ever received in an email.